# Having trouble injecting Aurelia's EventAggregator into a particular class

Tags: javascript, jspm, aurelia

I use the EventAggregator in several places in my app and everything works fine. However I’m having trouble injecting it into **one** of my classes. When the class constructor is called, the EventAggregator argument is undefined.

```
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(EventAggregator)
export class Test {
    constructor(eventAggregator) {
        debugger;
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }
}
```

When stopping at the `debugger;` line, the constructor’s eventAggregator argument is undefined.

This looks just like what I have done to use EventAggregator in many other classes, so what could be the issue?

Comment: are you using jspm- if so, what does `jspm inspect --forks` return?  What is the value of `EventAggregator` at your breakpoint?

Comment: @JeremyDanyow It returns:      Installed Forks

           npm:aurelia-event-aggregator 1.0.0-beta.1.2.0 1.0.0-beta.1.2.1
                    npm:aurelia-logging 1.0.0-beta.1.2.0 1.0.0-beta.1.2.1

Comment: @JeremyDanyow The value of EventAggregator is function EventAggregator() {....} but the eventAggregator argument is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has to do with forks (multiple version of the same package installed).

1. To clean this up, open your `config.js` file and delete everything inside the `map: {` node. For example- all [this](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/1.0.0/skeleton-esnext/config.js#L11-L201).
2. Then execute `jspm install`.
3. Then check for forks again. `jspm inspect --forks`
4. If you still have forks, execute `jspm install aurelia-_______` for [each aurelia item listed in your package.json](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/1.0.0/skeleton-esnext/package.json#L70-L82)

In fact- you may want to skip right to step 4- this will ensure you get the latest, which is now 1.0.0 (RTM) version of aurelia.

Comment: Went ahead and upgraded to Aurelia 1.0, but that didn't fix the problem.  It turns out that I was calling new() on the class to which I had just added the injection of EventAggregator. So when the class's constructor was called, the eventAggregator parameter wasn't passed, so it was undefined of course.

Comment: Ah- that would do it! At least you're upgraded and the forks are cleaned up

Comment: Now the question is, how do you use dependency injection in a class which is not a singleton since consumers won't have access to the injected classes when they call new()?  Use default arguments?

Comment: @inject(Factory.of(MyClass)) http://stackoverflow.com/a/39040268/725866

Comment: In the example, how is MyModel used within the App class? Normally it would be passed into the constructor and you can hold onto it with this.myModel = myModel and then use it as this.myModel. Plus, I don't get how the two classes in the example interact. Sorry I had to post here instead of on the other post but I don't have enough reputation points to do so.

Comment: Okay. I think I was looking at it in reverse. It appears that the **consumer** of the class (App in this case) needs to use Factory.of. Is that correct?

Comment: Alright. Now I've got it. Factory.of gives you access to the constructor with the injection arguments already set so they don't need to be passed by consumers. I have this all working now in my project. Thanks Jeremy!